# Why can't record log with option --log-file in ssserver?

Tags: python, logging, daemon, socks

```
pip install  shadowsocks
```

And set all the configuration in /etc/shadowsocks.json .

```
sudo ssserver -h |grep log
  --log-file LOG_FILE    log file for daemon mode
```

I want to record log for shadowsocks server in /home/user/ss.log.
Let's create a ssserver daemon.

Format1:

```
sudo vim   /etc/systemd/system/ss.service
[Unit]
Description=Shadowsocks
After=network.target

[Service]
User=root
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python   /usr/local/bin/ssserver  -c /etc/shadowsocks.json --log-file  /home/user/ss.log

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

sudo  systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl restart  ss
```

No record in /home/user/ss.log after many web page opened via shadowsocks.
Is a bug for the argument `--log-file` in ssserver or not?
It is no use to write as :

```
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python   /usr/local/bin/ssserver --log-file  /home/user/ss.log  -c /etc/shadowsocks.json
```

Format2:

```
sudo vim   /etc/systemd/system/ss.service
[Unit]
Description=Shadowsocks
After=network.target

[Service]
User=root
StandardOutput=journal
StandardError=journal
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python /usr/local/bin/ssserver -c /etc/shadowsocks.json  

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

To check log with command `sudo journalctl -u ss`.

Format3:

```
sudo vim   /etc/systemd/system/ss.service
[Unit]
Description=Shadowsocks
After=network.target

[Service]
User=root
ExecStart=/bin/bash -c "/usr/bin/python /usr/local/bin/ssserver -c /etc/shadowsocks.json >/home/user/ss.log  2>&1" 

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

It is verified that Format2 and Format3 can work properly,my puzzles is:
Why Format1  can't work?

Answer (score 0):

You should **start** the ssserver with this option:

```
/usr/bin/python  /usr/local/bin/ssserver  -c /etc/shadowsocks.json  --log-file /home/user/ss.log  start
```